# Avoid iterating with a Join (LinQ)

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Not the best title here, I know.

The thing I have this code and it looks awful. Is there a better way to write this?

```
foreach (Agency agency in local.Agencies.GetAll().Where(a => a.Active).Where(a => a.Mandatory))
{
    if (agencies.Where(a => a.AgencyId == agency.Id).Any())
    {
        mandatoryFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

So  `local` is my EF context, and `agencies` is a list sent by the client. I need to check if in that list sent by the there's at least one mandatory Agency.

Comment: This code is not awful if you use it in linq2entity it will iterate items.

Answer (score 0):

```
mandatoryFound = local.Agencies.GetAll().Where(a => a.Active && a.Mandatory && agencies.Any(ag => ag.AgencyId == a.Id)).Any()
```

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault() != null` is the same as `.Any()`

Comment: Why `FirstOrDefault()` and not Any?

Comment: tha's no good... i get the following error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'XXX.PCNAgency'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: `agencies` is a list of `PCNAgency`